# How to make my frontend Javascript code more modular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, modularity

I'm working on an open-source Node.Js / express app, which visualizes text notes as a network to provide a visual summary of the connections between all the different notes to the user.

It's quite heavy on the frontend, using a lot of functions to filter and process the notes, visualize them as a graph using `sigma.js` library and so on.

At the moment, all my frontend code is inside one file:

https://github.com/noduslabs/infranodus/blob/master/views/entries.ejs

I want to make it more modular.

I know the question is a bit broad, but could somebody give me an indication what strategy I should take to make that code more modular?

For example, should I just separate all the functions and put them into the separate .js files?

Or is there a framework I could use? Maybe something that people normally use with Node.Js?

Any recommendation would be appreciated. I'm asking your help because I want to see what are the options out there.

Thank you!

Comment: Organizing your code as CommonJS modules (what Node.js uses) comes to mind.

Comment: Check [wepback](http://webpack.github.io/). We're using it in our node.js project to build all our client-side code. We switched to it from [require.js](http://requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

[CommonJS and browserify](http://browserify.org) and [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) are two good options at the moment. You might want to read up on CommonJS (what node currently uses) and ECMAScript 6 modules (the official modularization spec for JS which is most likely to be the next long-term format for modular JS code).